# Perl Cant enter a for loop with URI::QueryParam

Tags: perl, uri, query-string

I have the following piece of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

open (URLS, "<urls.txt");
open (EXTRAPARAMS, "<extraparams.txt");

my @words = (<EXTRAPARAMS>);  

while ( my $URL = <URLS>) {
        my $uri = URI->new($URL);
        print "GETS THIS FAR\n";
        print "$uri\n";

    for my $key ($uri->query_param) {
         print "CANT GET HERE\n";                        #why does it not get here?
         my $org = $uri->query_param($key);
         for my $word (@words) {
             for ("$org$word", $word, "$word$org") {
                 $uri->query_param($key, $_);
                 print $uri->as_string, $/;
             }
         }
         $uri->query_param($key, $org);
    }
}
```

**The problem I am having**

I am able to read in each of the urls from the URLS text file and print them, but i cannot seem to enter the `for` loop for some reason.

**Is there something obvious I am overlooking or not doing because I cant seem to work out why its not getting there?**

It may be nothing to do with the URI::QueryParam stuff and just an error I have made but I cant find it.

I have looked at the docs for URI::QueryParam and everything appears to be written/formatted how it should be as far as the `$key` and `query_param` parts are concerned as far as I can see, so I don't know whats wrong?

Your help is much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Can you show a sample URL for which it doesn't work?  If it doesn't enter the `for` loop, that suggests there are no params.

Comment: @dan1111 - Yes I think you may have just answered my question.

Comment: Aside from showing the input, you should also check the return value of your `open` statements, to make sure they succeeded.

Comment: It certainly wont be a mistake ill make twice, and yes I would do normally using `or die` and so on, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplification of your code works fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $uri = URI->new("http://www.foo.com?bar=baz&sproing=blargh");

for my $key ($uri->query_param) {
     print "$key\n";
}
```

Output:

```
bar
sproing
```

The problem is almost certainly with your data: your URL isn't correctly formatted or doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: Yes were right, the reason was because the url's did not contain any parameters, thanks for your help

Comment: @perl-user, glad to help.  We've all made those types of mistakes!